# Wiring a rocker switch with pilot light so light is on when switch is off

Tags: switch, light-fixture

I have a single switch with a pilot light next to a two-function switch in a double gang box. They are both used to control a three function fan/light/night light in a bathroom.

Everything is working fine, except the pilot light in the single function switch is on when the light is on, rather than when it is off, which seems like the point of the pilot light.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You'll certainly need a different switch. You may also need to wire the switch box differently, depending on how the pilot light works (needing its own neutral, or being powered by "parasitic" current through the load).

Comment: Depending on how the switch is internally wired, you might be able to but the load on the line, and the line on the load in order to get the desired operation. You have a part number?

Answer (score 2):

You have a pilot light switch. Some are **on** when the circuit is **on**, others are **on** when the circuit is **off** and some can be set either way. It sounds like what you want is an illuminated switch, one that guides you to the switch in the dark so you can turn it on.

While some pilot light switches can do that (and yours might), the simple [illuminated switches](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-Illuminated-Toggle-Switch-Clear-R50-01461-0LC/202035012) generally look better, and the toggle itself is usually glowing.

```
Links are for illustration only and not an endorsement of products or sources.
```